# InputConnectionWrapper: finishingComposingText on inactive InputConnection

Tags: android

My logcat is showing this warning when I am trying to put an entry into my app. Probably, somewhere within my EditText handling is throwing this.

```
01-24 10:44:34.470 2404-2404/org.andrewjakevillegas.andrewjakevillegas.mymedlist W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
01-24 10:44:35.472 2404-2404/org.andrewjakevillegas.andrewjakevillegas.mymedlist W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

I have a main activity that calls another activity to add a drug entry and save it into a db. This addmed activity has some EditTexts that captures data.

Have anybody encountered this type of situation?

```
public class AddMed extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button mAddMed;
EditText mDrugName2;
EditText mDose2;
EditText mRoute2;
EditText mFrequency2;
EditText mRefilldate2;
EditText mExpirationdate2;
DBAdapter dbcon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_add_med );

    dbcon = new DBAdapter(this);

    mDrugName2 = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.drugName2 );
    mDose2 = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.dose2 );
    mRoute2 = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.route2 );
    mFrequency2 = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.frequency2 );
    mRefilldate2 = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.refillDate2 );
    mExpirationdate2 = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.expirationDate );
    mAddMed = (Button) findViewById( R.id.update );


    mAddMed.setOnClickListener( this );
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE  );
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow( mDrugName2.getWindowToken(), 0 );

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.addMedicine:
            String drugname = mDrugName2.getText().toString();
            String dose = mDose2.getText().toString();
            String route = mRoute2.getText().toString();
            String frequency = mFrequency2.getText().toString();
            String refilldate = mRefilldate2.getText().toString();
            String expirationdate = mExpirationdate2.getText().toString();
            dbcon.createMed( drugname, dose, route, frequency, refilldate, expirationdate );
            Intent main = new Intent( AddMed.this, MedMainActivity.class );
            startActivity( main );


            break;

        default:
            break;


    }

}
```

}